# How to execute program with parameters which I got?

Tags: bash

I have some script a.py and can execute it with some parameters

```
./a.py 1 2 --h 'Hi!'
```

Also I have bash script `sh.sh`. And I want to do something like this:

```
./sh.sh ./a.py 1 2 --h 'Hi!'
```

And then `a.py` start with these parameters. What I should write in `sh.sh`?

Comment: Very simple example here :) https://how-to.fandom.com/wiki/How_to_read_command_line_arguments_in_a_bash_script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the command:

```
./sh.sh ./a.py 1 2 --h 'Hi!'
```

Then inside the shell script, the contents of the array `$@` will be:

```
'./a.py' '1' '2' '--h' 'Hi!'
```

So if you want to run that, you can just use:

```
"$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

Below the list of special variables provided by the shell that you can use in your shell script directly.

```
Variable     Variable Details
$#          :  Total number of arguments passed to script
$0          :  Script name itself
$1 to $n    :  $1 for the first arguments, $2 for second argument till $n for n’th arguments. From 10’th argument, we must enclose them in curly braces eg. ${10}, ${11}
$*          :  Values of all the arguments. All agruments are double quoted
$@          :  Values of all the arguments
$?          :  Exit status id of last command
$$          :  Process ID of current shell
$!          :  Process id of last command
```